# How to get object values using object ID property in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8, data-binding, observablecollection

this is my first experience on windows phone 8 application development.
I have a problem which I mention below, could you please help me to figure out it.

I show data from ActivityViewModel via Data Binding in Activities.xaml
When user tap to activity item, I send ActivityID to ActivityDetails.xaml.
I am trying to call object which I created as AccountAction by using ActivityID.

How can I get object values (ActivityImage, ActivityName, ActivityAmont ...) by using ActivityID in ActivityDetails.xaml.cs?

*ActivityViewModel:*

```
public class ActivityViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<AccountAction> ActivityItemCollection { get; set; }

    public ActivityViewModel()
    {
        ActivityItemCollection = new ObservableCollection<AccountAction>();


        ActivityItemCollection.Add(new AccountAction()
        {
            ActivityID = "SP0001",
            ActivityImage = "/Images/Logos/e-bay.png"
            ActivityName = "E-Bay",
            ActivityAmount = "100,00",
            ActivityDate = "Today",
            ActivityHour = "11:49"
        });

       .
       .
       .

    }
}
```

*Activities.xaml.cs*

```
 private void StackPanel_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        var _ActivityID = Convert.ToString(((StackPanel)sender).Tag);
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/ActivityDetails.xaml?ActivityID=" + _ActivityID, UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

*ActivityDetails.xaml.cs*

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        string ActivityID = "";

        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("ActivityID", out ActivityID))
        {
            ReferanceNumber.Text = ActivityID;

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        string ActivityID;
        if (e.IsNavigationInitiator  && this.NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("ActivityID", out ActivityID))
        {
          ActivityID= int.Parse(ActivityID);

        }
    }
```

**EDIT:**

You can get the data related to activityid by using linq

```
AccountAction result = ActivityItemCollection.FirstOrDefault(act=>act.ActivityID == ActivityID);
```

Then you can get object values like result.ActivityName

Comment: @efendi check modified answer!

Comment: Thanks but I've got ActivityItemCollection does not exist in current context error. :/

Comment: @efendi You need to create the object of viewmodel and then do this, ViewModel vm = new ViewModel(), vm.ActivityItemCollection..FirstOrDefault(act=>act.ActivityID == ActivityID);